# Java Swing MVC dynamic components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller

I have used the MVC pattern extensively in web applications in C# ASP.net and PHP CodeIgniter + Laravel, but now I have to implement it for a java Swing application and I'm a bit lost when it comes to actually dynamically adding elements (like a JPanel) to a View from an event. In any Web MVC framework, I would simply return a partial view and inject it in a div. More explanations:

I have a View that has only one thing: a button that the MainController listens on. When I click the button, the view tells the controller to call the method "buttonClicked()". The result of that should be that a JPanel is created and added to the view, but how do I do that in Java Swing MVC? Like I said, in a web MVC framework, I would probably do something like "return new partialView(model)".

Since the only classes that should be dependent on the Swing framework are the Views, I understand that the JPanel is created in there, but isn't the controller (or the model) supposed to tell the view where to place it? How does that work?

Thanks. I hope by thoughts were clear enough, I'm just starting with java.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I guess I didn't communicate clearly what I wanted. So, I already have a BoxLayout in the view, but what I'm wondering is: what is the role of the controller in the process of adding a new JPanel to the window? Does it simply pass the JPanel data (name, text, etc.) while the view creates the JPanel and uses the model to fill the fields?
And when I'm in the actual "buttonClicked()" method, how do I say to the view "Add a new JPanel"? Do I call some kind of "update()" method in the model?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the Model should be concerned with all the logic and processing physics of the output. In this case, that is the change in state of the main view's JPanel that is induced by user input .Therefore it is the business of the Model and the Model alone. However, the controller's job is to communicate that change to the view and the view is still responsible for displaying the change. This way, the single responsibility principle of the MVC model is sustained.

Here is one way this can be done:

View:

- Implement a method in the view class that takes in a JPanel argument, equates it the view object's panel and updates the UI of the panel(e.g. `newPanelUpdate(JPanel panel){...}`).

Model:

- Add a new `JPanel` field(e.g.`newPanel`) with it's 'setters and getters'.

Controller:

- Implement an `actionListener` that once the button is clicked, would get new JPanel's value from the model and pass it as an argument of the newPanelUpdate() method.

Main Program:

- Here you create the new JPanel you want to show up once the button is clicked and set the JPanel field in the Model to it.

This method assumes that you will use only 3 classes to represent the the Model, View, and Controller. In reality, the model implementation might not be as convenient but will still operate on the same principles.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldnt need a model in your case. Just add the panel to the view within the controller. Having your model use JPanels or else Gui components would violate the reason you use MVC in the first place.

```
buttonClicked() {
    mView.add(new JPanel());
}
```

If you would want i.e. to store an int of how many panels you have in your view, then you could implement a model having that integer together with a function addPanel(). Then your buttonClicked() looks like this:

```
buttonClicked(){
    mModel.addPanel();
}

Model.addPanel(){
    amountPanels++;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
```

In this case your View would be an Observer and add the panel in its update()

```
@Override
update() {
   add.(new JPanel());
}
```